# Is there any way to clone a running VM in Azure?

Tags: azure

I deployed a VM (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) on Azure, ssh-ed in to it and made some configurations. Now I want to launch more instances like this. On AWS, you could use "Launch More Like This" action; however, I could not find a way of doing this on Azure.

How can I duplicate the VM without stopping it??

I have already seen another similar question in SO ([Can you replicate an azure virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743725/can-you-replicate-an-azure-virtual-machine)), but my question is a further one.

In Azure's official tutorial, you have to take following steps:

1. Deallocate the source VM (<-- Why do I have to?)
2. Generalize the VM (this makes it never relaunchable)
3. Capture the generalized VM (<-- Why do I have to?)
4. Create new VMs from the template (You will need NIC things which I don't know much)

I just want a copy of currently running VM, **without deallocating it**. On AWS, you can create AMI without relaunching the instance. Or, at least, the instance could be relaunched. How to make a copy of a VM without making it disabled (when generalized) or deallocated??

Note: I use Mac so I have no access to PowerShell.

Comment: You can follow this article to clone an existing VM without deallocating or even stopping it - Very useful https://www.techmanyu.com/how-to-quickly-clone-a-vm-in-azure/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. This is something I really struggled with when I started using Azure because it does not work like you may expect it to.

1. You deallocate to help generalize the VM. Directly from Azure documentation

> Deprovisioning deletes files and data in an effort to "generalize" the image. Only run this command on a VM that you intend to capture as an image. It does not guarantee that the image is cleared of all sensitive information or is suitable for redistribution to third parties.

2. Yes generalizing the vm makes it never relaunchable. The purpose of generalizing the image is so that when you create a new vm based off the image things like the computer name or other settings you probably don't want duplicated across multiple Vms aren't duplicated but are able to made unique each time you spin up a new VM based on that image.
3. You capture the vm so that you have an image of the vm. This image can be reused to create instances of the vm you had running.
4. Azure provides lots of documentation and it's not too hard to learn about Azure networking.

Using the template and image you can create copies of the VM you had running before. Yes the VM you had running is gone but now you can spin up more instances just like it using the template and image. You're not going to be able to just copy the VM running in Azure currently. That could change in the future.

Once you have the image and template why do you need to copy an already running instance? You should be able to spin up as many of the VMs as you need with those.

Comment: Any idea or references how can I clone a VM on Azure using c#?